# Extracting first and second component of ordered pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For Kuratowski there are expressions for extracting the first and second element of an ordered pair. However, I could not find any literature about extracting the components of an ordered pair in short notation, i.e. $(a,b) = \lbrace a, \lbrace a,b \rbrace \rbrace $.

So I tried to come up with one of my own. Let $\pi_1(p)$ represent the first element of the tuple $p$, and $\pi_2(p)$ the second.

$$ \pi_1(p) = \bigcup \lbrace x \in p : \exists c (x \in c \wedge c \in p)  \rbrace$$

This seems to work for $(a,b)$ whether $a=b$ or not, because due to regularity (everything here in ZF) $a \notin a$.

$$ \pi_2(p) = \bigcup \lbrace x \in \bigcup p : \lbrace x, \pi_1(p)  \rbrace  \in p \rbrace$$

I hope this works, too, however it seems ugly that it uses the definition of $\pi_1(p)$.

Do these expressions work as intended?

Is there another, already established and nicer way for extracting the first and second element?

---

**EDIT:**

Trying to prove the first definition.

Let $p = \lbrace a, \lbrace a,b \rbrace \rbrace$ such that $ a \neq b$. Then
$a \in \lbrace x \in p : \exists c (x \in c \wedge c \in p)  \rbrace$, because $a \in p$ and there exists  $c=\lbrace a,b \rbrace$ such that $a \in c \wedge c \in p$.

As $x \in p$, all sets unequal to $\lbrace a, b \rbrace$ and unequal to $a$ are not in $\lbrace x \in p : \exists c (x \in c \wedge c \in p)  \rbrace$, because they are not in $p$.

If $\lbrace a, b \rbrace$ were in $\lbrace x \in p : \exists c (x \in c \wedge c \in p)  \rbrace$, then either $\lbrace a, b \rbrace \in a$ or $\lbrace a, b \rbrace \in \lbrace a, b \rbrace$. The axiom of regularity asserts that this is not the case.

Therefore, $\lbrace x \in p : \exists c (x \in c \wedge c \in p)  \rbrace = \lbrace a \rbrace$ and $\pi_1(p) = \bigcup \lbrace a \rbrace = a$.

If $ a= b$, then $p = \lbrace a, \lbrace a \rbrace \rbrace$. This means that $\pi_1(p)$ is either $a$ or $\lbrace a \rbrace$. For $a$ there exists a $c = \lbrace a \rbrace$ such that $a \in c \wedge c \in p$. However $\lbrace a \rbrace$ is barred for the same reasons as above. Therefore $\pi_1(p) = a$.

---

**EDIT 2**

Trying to proof the second statement.

Let $p = \lbrace a, \lbrace a, b \rbrace \rbrace$. In this case $\pi_1(p) = a$. Then $\bigcup p$ contains $a$, $b$ and all elements of $a$. Hence, $b$ is in $\bigcup p$ and $\lbrace b, \pi_1(p) \rbrace = \lbrace b, a \rbrace$ is in $p$. Therefore, $b$ is in $\lbrace x \in \bigcup p : \lbrace x, \pi_1(p)  \rbrace  \in p \rbrace$.

The only other element of $p$ is $a$. So far $a$ to be in $\lbrace x \in \bigcup p : \lbrace x, \pi_1(p)  \rbrace  \in p \rbrace$, the following must hold: $a = \lbrace a, \pi_1(p) \rbrace = \lbrace a \rbrace$, which is not possible due to regularity.

Therefore, $b$ is the only element, i.e. $\lbrace x \in \bigcup p : \lbrace x, \pi_1(p)  \rbrace  \in p \rbrace = \lbrace b \rbrace$. We see that $\pi_2(p) = \bigcup \lbrace b \rbrace = b$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, $b$ is a possible $c$, which is required for $a$ to comply with $x \in c \wedge c \in p$.

Comment: @RobArthan I changed $\pi_n$ to $\pi_n(p)$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't see it. In the formula for $\pi_1(p)$, the $x$ has to comply with $x \in p$, so only members of $b$ which are either equal to $a$ (which doesn't affect ¿?) or equal to $\lbrace a, b \rbrace$ (which is barred by regularity) can contribute. Could you construct a counterexample with a certain $b$ that breaks my formula. I would be very thankful.

Comment: Due to the axiom of regularity, $b$ is not a possible $c$ (since $x,c\in p$ and $x\in c,$ this would imply $b=a$ and $\{b\}\in b$.)

Comment: I see. In my second comment, I meant $\lbrace a, b \rbrace$ is a possible $c$, hence allowing $a$ to equal $x$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Does the formula for $\pi_1(p)$ find the first element?

Comment: Both your $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ seem correct to me.

Comment: Apologies. I think your ideas look good now to me.